# filtering div classes based on dropdown selection with jquery

Tags: jquery, filter, hide, show

I'm using Jquery 1.6. I have a dropdown list that  has a bunch of options.

I'm trying to make my dropdown hide divs based on the value of dropdown.

If I select from the dropdown list "option 1.8" i want it to look at the value attribute and based on the last three characters in the value find all div classes that end with the same characters and hide those.

The script below works but the problem is that i want it so that my "value" in my dropdown doesn't have to be the same name as my class names I have in my html. This is why i wanted it to find the last part of the values.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$("#version-select").bind("change", function() {
    $("div").filter('.' + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
});
});  
</script>


<select name="version-select" id="version-select">
    <option value="option_1_6">Option 1.6</option>
    <option value="option_1_7">Option 1.7</option>
    <option value="option_1_8">Option 1.8</option>
    <option value="option_2_0">Option 2.0</option>
</select>

<div class="class_1_6">
<img src="my_path/to/my_images"/>
<p>some text</p>
</div>

<div class="table_info_1_7">
<img src="my_path/to/my_images"/>
<p>some text</p>
</div>

<div class="class_1_8">
<img src="my_path/to/my_images"/>
<p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Any help with getting it to find the last part of the values based on the option i select in the dropdown would be helpfull.

Comment: I think those DIV's should be inside a list (UL element)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sendmetamil/8BL5q/3/). I have used [jqueryEndsWithSelector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

```
$('#version-select').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    var lastThreeChars = val.substring(val.length - 3);
    $('div').hide();
    $('div[class$="' + lastThreeChars + '"]').show();
});
```

Comment: Just `$( '[class$=" + this.value.slice( -3 ) + "]' )`. No need for those two variables...

Comment: This works perfectly with one problem now. It seems as though all children elements show/hide EXCEPT for those that are <div> elements. I tried using .siblings() before show and hide methods however that doesn't seem to work

Comment: @cibit: See my update. If you want to hide the childrens of the selected div, that ll do.

Comment: i don't want to hide the childrens of the selected div i want it to only show the one that is selected and hide all the others. A use case would be a user has three options in the dropdown let say 1_6, 1_7, 1_8 and if they select 1_7 its should hide 1_6 and 1_8 divs including the children and then only show 1_7 and its children.

Comment: @cibit: Sorry for the delay pal. I have just updated my answer. I hope it helps. I just removed `.children().hide()` from the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like:

```
$(function(){   
    $("#version-select").bind("change", function() {
        var value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        var last3chars = value.substring( value.length - 3)
        $("div").hide();
        $(".class_" + last3chars).show();
    });
});
```

See a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7YSPS/2/